# Factory Girl isn't scoping in an integration spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, factory-bot

Here's my integration spec. I would like to define those users at the global scope so I can make expectations based on them in all of the spec's expectations. However, doing this means the variables `@user_0` and the rest aren't available inside the expectation.

Notice I've got that `ap @user_0` in the first expectation to print the hash. It returns nil.

First question is, how do I make globally available variables in an integration spec?

It's worth noting that if I `build` the variables in the expectation, everything works fine then, it's just when the variables are built outside the expectation.

Am I right in thinking that this is an error? I mean surely I'm going to want to write expectations that use users defined in other specs? Or is each spec a sort of self contained thing, and if transitional fixtures are turned on, the test database is wiped between each expectation? It's just odd that these instance variables aren't scoped by default, as though it's been done on purpose.

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'factory_girl'

@user_0 = FactoryGirl.build(:user_0)
@user_1 = FactoryGirl.build(:user_1)
@user_2 = FactoryGirl.build(:user_2)
@user_3 = FactoryGirl.build(:user_3)

describe "foo", js: true do        
    it "can create a user" do
        ap @user_0 #=> nil
   end
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't assigning the instance variables in a `background` or `before` block?

Comment: No, sounds like a good idea ><

Comment: Yeah using a before block did it. I'm new to integration testing and the syntax is a little different so that threw me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add call to `:before` method to evaluate the specified block before each *it* operation:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'factory_girl'

describe "foo", js: true do        
   before :each do
      @user_0 = FactoryGirl.build(:user_0)
      @user_1 = FactoryGirl.build(:user_1)
      @user_2 = FactoryGirl.build(:user_2)
      @user_3 = FactoryGirl.build(:user_3)
   end

   it "can create a user" do
      ap @user_0 #=> nil
   end
end
```

And make sure that your user factory has been properly written.